# Check white-space in Char and Check Digits in Strings

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, char

So I'm faced with this problem:

> Write a program that reads a text file and checks for correctness of
>   the word. A word is correct if it starts with a character only and
>   does not contain any number in it.   The input ends with a semi-colon
>   ;

I tried to do this in two ways:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char text;

    cout<<"Enter a group of words ending with a semicolon ; ";
    cin>>text;
    int ctr=0;
    while(text !=';')
    {
     if (text  == ' ')   ctr++;
        cin>>text;
    }

    cout<<ctr;



    return 0;
}
```

But this fails to increment at spaces.

I tried the same using Strings instead of Chars, the word counters work but     `text == "0"` (for example) wouldn't work correctly too..

Why wouldn't the Char read the white-space and why wouldn't the String read the digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >> text` ignores leading whitespace.

When `text` is a single `char`, `>>` will then read the next character if available, otherwise fail.

When `text` is a `char` array, `>>` will then read characters until it encounters whitespace, reaches its max width, or fails.

Either way, `>>` does not return the whitespace that it skipped.  So `text` will never equal `' '`.  Besides, your counter should be counting the actual words read, not the spaces between them.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a group of words ending with a semicolon ; ";

    char text[512];
    int ctr = 0;

    while (cin >> setw(512) >> text)
    {
        if (strcmp(text, ";") == 0) break;
        ++ctr;
    }

    cout << ctr;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest method is to read your input into a `std::string` then search for a character that is not in a set of valid characters.

For example:

```
const std::string valid_characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                                     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
std::string text_from_input;
std::getline(std::cin, text_from_input);
std::string::size_type position_of_invalid_char =
    text_from_input.find_first_not_of(valid_characters);
```